# post to database

Tags: php

So i have so code that takes a message/post users insert and its meant to post it to a database and this then displays and a seperate page. Ive got the displaying park working fine its just trying to insert to database which is the problem

This code...

```
<?php  
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
mysql_select_db("test");     
$time = time();  
mysql_query "INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, dated);" 
VALUES (NULL,'$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','0','$time');      
echo "Thread Posted.<br><a href='Untitled9.php'>Return</a>";  
?>
```

wont post the infomation into the database!

Why is this and how can it be resolved?

```
  id      int(11)                          No None AUTO_INCREMENT               
  title   varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci  No None                
  message text           latin1_swedish_ci  No None                
  author  varchar(255)   latin1_swedish_ci  No None                
  replies int(11)                           No None                
  posted  varchar(255)   latin1_swedish_ci  No None                
  votes_up int(11)                          No 0                
  votes_down int(11)                        No 0
```

Comment: Dear sweet baby jesus please sanitize your input.

Comment: I think I die inside a little every time I see this many sql injection points.

Comment: i havent learnt about SQL injection yet. This is not yet on the web and i look to protect against hacking after all is done

Comment: You don't apear to have time in your table.

Comment: time should be 'posted' as the existing data in there this is posted and that displays correct. Should i change code from 'time' to posted? would this stop everything not working?

Comment: "and i look to protect against hacking after all is done" — why write it incorrectly and then have to go back and rewrite it correctly, when you could just write it correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Should be posted not dated.

Heres your problem:

```
mysql_query "INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, posted);" 
VALUES (NULL,'$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','0','$time');
```

Change it to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, posted) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','$time');");
```

I see you have null values also, this makes me believe your using an ID with an auto increment, if this is the case, you need to supply this also.  Example:

**Edit: Here**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads (id,title, message, author, posted) VALUES (NULL,'$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','$time');");
```

**Note inserting values straight from post data is unsafe and leaves you open to various attacks.**

Comment: just saw.. Your code took away the error code but nothing is still posting :/

Comment: Can you edit your post and give us a little more information, such as your table layout etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query "INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, dated);" 
VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','$time');
```

You ended the String to early. Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, dated)
  VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','$time')");
```

Also, your code is very likely to become a target of SQL-Injections. You should use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)-class and a [PreparedStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to insert your posts.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are trying to add to the new row are more that the assigned values .

```
mysql_query "INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, dated);"
```

that are 4 values you want to set

```
VALUES (NULL,'$_POST[title]','$_POST[message]','$_POST[author]','0','$time');
```

and you are assigning 6 values.

which is not possible

Also validate $_POST data = read this [Never trust user input](http://members.ii.net/~a.koepke/never-trust-user-data.html).

And read the manual [PHP & MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon was ending your sql statment. Your query wasn't finished. You still needed to specify the values you wanted to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Number of issues :

1. if you put $_POST[] inside a string you need to put it in braces {$_POST[]}  or PHP will not decipher the variable
2. next the names of the variables in the $_POST[] need to be quoted so that PHP does not think they are CONSTANTS, so they need to be like $_POST['title'] or $_POST["title"]
3. As others have said you need to protect against SQL injection by filtering the posted vars. Safest way to do this is to use PDO and I have included an example below. You can improve on this.
4. turn on error reporting so you can see errors while debugging

Here's tested code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$user='root';
$pass='';
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost'; //for PDO later

mysql_connect("localhost",$user , $pass);  
mysql_select_db("test");     
$time = time();  
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
// using braces {}
$sql=<<<SQL
INSERT INTO threads (title, message, author, posted) 
VALUES ('{$_POST['title']}','{$_POST['message']}','{$_POST['author']}','$time')

SQL;

echo "$_POST[title]"."Thread Posted.<br><a href='Untitled9.php'>Return</a>";

// now a PDO version of the same
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();die;
}

$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT ino threads (title, message, author, posted)
                  VALUES (:title,:message,:author,:posted)");
$sth->execute(array(':title' => $_POST['title'],':message' => $_POST['message'], ':author' => $_POST['author'] ,':posted' => $time));
echo "Affected rows=".$sth->rowCount().",we are on line=".__LINE__."<br />";
echo $_POST['title']." Thread Posted.<br><a href='Untitled9.php'>Return</a>";

} // close if $_POST
```